# How to determine which one is training and testing in scikit-learn MLPRegressor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I have two dataset (training and testing), they both have the exact same columns of features and label, only different inside (the numbers and values). Here's my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

datatraining = pd.read_csv("datatrain.csv")

datatesting = pd.read_csv("datatest.csv")

columns = ["Full","Id","Id & PPDB","Id & Words Sequence","Id & Synonyms","Id & Hypernyms","Id & Hyponyms"]

labeltrain = datatraining["Gold Standard"].values
featurestrain = datatraining[list(columns)].values


labeltest = datatesting["Gold Standard"].values
featurestest = datatesting[list(columns)].values

X_train = featurestrain
y_train = labeltrain

X_test = featurestest
y_test = labeltest

mlp = MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', hidden_layer_sizes=50, max_iter=1000, learning_rate='constant')

mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Accuracy training : {:.3f}'.format(mlp.score(X_train, y_train)))
print

mlp.fit(X_test, y_test)

print('Accuracy testing : {:.3f}'.format(mlp.score(X_test, y_test)))
print
```

I still doubt that my code is correct to find train and test score, because I see no differentiator to determine which one is training and which another is testing. I see that both are training, or both are testing.
Anyone can explain how to determine it? Or is my code already correct? Thanks

Comment: It's typically done by dividing your data into two sets of data points, chosen randomly without replacement.  Could be 50/50, or bootstrapped as five different combinations of 80/20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you fit your model on the training, you shouldn't fit it again on the testing. Instead, you should evaluate the performance of your model using the test set. Hence, you need to remove the row

```
mlp.fit(X_test, y_test)
```

from your code. Then using the row

```
print('Accuracy testing : {:.3f}'.format(mlp.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

you will be able to evaluate the performance of your model on unseen data.

Comment: I remove the row, but it shows negative testing score and it always change everytime I run

Comment: The score is negative because it is R^2 score, which indeed may be negative (see here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.score). The score is different each time because there is randomness in the process. Try to add the row np.random.seed(1) at the top of your code, to make results consistent.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand the use of `np.random.seed(1)` because I'm new in using scikit and numpy. May I have another example for that? Thanks

Comment: When you fit MLPRegressor, there is randomness in the process. For example, the data is shuffled randomly. Hence, each time you run the code, you may get different result. By setting a fixed seed to the random state (see here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) you make sure that each time the random process behaves in the same way. For example, the shuffles would be the same each time you run the code and so on. See this as well:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState